# How to resolve a firebase extension update stuck spinning?

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I'm attempting to update the Run Payments with Stripe on Firebase however it just spins and never finishes.

I'm currently running 0.2.4.

Comment: Can you check your Cloud Functions logs and add what you see there?

Comment: It's probably best to reach out to support, definitely something they can dig into. Update should not be getting stuck.